# What python module to use for neural net application?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am looking for an **easy to use** python module I can use to create and train a neuronal network for pattern recognition (or, more precise, I have several short audio files containing a spoken word or a spoken phrase, and I want to use a machine learning/deep learning algorithm to train the network so it can recognize which word/phrase was spoken).

So basically I have several input data elements (i.e. the same word spoken from the same person 10 times, 20 timex etc), and I have the output word/phrase.

What is a good python module to use for this kind of training?

Answer (score 1):

[Keras](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/) with the [Tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) backend:

- [Docs](https://keras.io/)
- [MNIST Tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/)

### Installation

As a beginner, I recommend NOT to use a GPU. Things will be way slower, but you will have an easier time with the installation. You can always uninstall and install CUDA + Tensorflow with GPU support later.

1. [Install Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)
2. Install Kears:

It could be as simple as that:

```
$ pip install tensorflow
$ pip install keras
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, you may like to use [EpyNN](https://epynn.net).

EpyNN is an educational ecosystem that provides:

- Educational API
- Educational workflows
- Extensive documentation with code/maths/diagrams/text

EpyNN was validated against Tensorflow/Keras and it provides identical results for identical configurations.

If you want to understand what's behind the API you use, give a try to EpyNN.